# change global variable value using a local function in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a very simple java script code. I want to change the value of global variable using a local function. I want that when I call the `value1()` function than the output should be "2". How can I perform this

```
var xhr=1;
alert(xhr);

function vari(){
    xhr=2;
    alert(xhr);
}

function value1(){ 
    //here the value should be 2
    alert(xhr);       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine! You have to invoke `vari()` though, but you know that, right? You cannot expect variables to change, if you do not call the functions that change the values!

Comment: When you call `vari()` before `value1()`, it works! If it does not work when you try it, you are doing something wrong. Not a useful comment by the way!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `xhr` in your `value1()` function will be `2` *only* if you have already called `vari()`.

Comment: i have called the vari() but still the value is 1

Answer (score 0):

From the given scenario, I think that you are calling `value1()` function before calling `vari()`.
That's why you are getting 1 as output.

Try the below code

```
      var xhr=1;
      alert(xhr);
      function vari(){
            xhr=2;
                alert(xhr);
      }

      function value1(){ 
          //here the value should be 2
               alert(xhr);       

      }
      window.onload = vari();
      window.onload = value1();
```